# Problems with deploying first smart contracts

Tags: solidity, everscale

Good day everyone!

I'm trying to deploy the first smart contracts according to the helloWorld manuals, but I'm getting an error please see the snippet. Tell me, please, what can be done about this? Tried lot of way to fix it but failed.

Thanks in advance!

```js
import { Command } from ""commander"";
import prompts, { PromptObject } from ""prompts"";
import { isNumeric, Migration } from ""./utils"";
const program = new Command();
const migration = new Migration();
async function main() {
  const promptsData: PromptObject[] = [];
  program
    .allowUnknownOption()
    .option(""-kn, --key_number <key_number>"", ""Public key number"")
    .option(
      ""-b, --balance <balance>"",
      ""Initial balance in EVERs (will send from Giver)"",
    );
  program.parse(process.argv);
  const options = program.opts();
  if (!options.key_number) {
    promptsData.push({
      type: ""text"",
      name: ""keyNumber"",
      message: ""Public key number"",
      validate: value => (isNumeric(value) ? true : ""Invalid number""),
    });
  }
  if (!options.balance) {
    promptsData.push({
      type: ""text"",
      name: ""balance"",
      message: ""Initial balance (will send from Giver)"",
      validate: value => (isNumeric(value) ? true : ""Invalid number""),
    });
  }

  const response = await prompts(promptsData);

  const keyNumber = +(options.key_number || response.keyNumber);
  const balance = +(options.balance || response.balance);

  const signer = (await locklift.keystore.getSigner(keyNumber.toString()))!;
  let accountsFactory = locklift.factory.getAccountsFactory(""Account"");

  const { account: Account } = await accountsFactory.deployNewAccount({
    publicKey: signer.publicKey,
    initParams: {
      _randomNonce: locklift.utils.getRandomNonce(),
    },
    constructorParams: {},
    value: locklift.utils.toNano(balance),
  });
  migration.store(Account, ""account"");
  console.log(`Account deployed at: ${Account.address}`);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
    process.exit(1);
  });"
```

Answer (score 0):

Crashes on an attempt to collect Account contract assembly artefacts
There is no such thing in the build folder!